# PHP update command not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have been banging my head against the wall on this for about 2 hours now and I cannot figure out what im doing wrong. I am simply trying to update a MySQL database with new information. but when I click "Update Information" nothing is happening.

```
<div id="tabs-1"> 
<?php  

 //update main informaion

if(isset($_POST["toolnameupdate"])){

  $companyname1 = "";

  $toolname1 = "";

 include_once("../php_includes/db_connect.php");

 $companyname1 = $_POST['clientname'];

 $toolname1 = $_POST['webtoolname'];

 $sql = "UPDATE siteinformation SET clientname = $companyname1, srcname = $toolname1";

$query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Location: user.php');
}
?>     
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
<legend><strong>Main Title Information</strong></legend>
<div id="prompt">Client Company Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" value="<? echo $companyname; ?>"/></div>
<div id="prompt">Web Tool Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="webtoolname" id="webtoolname" value="<? echo $toolname; ?>"/></div>
<div id="prompt"><input type="submit" id="toolnameupdate" name="toolnameupdate" value="Update Information" /></div><div id="answer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="prompt">&nbsp;</div><div id="answer">&nbsp;</div>
</fieldset> 
</form>
  </div>
```

Can anyone see where it is missing information?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a <form> tag....

Comment: Firstly.. sanitize your variables. Secondly.. I don't think using parenthesis in the $_POST superglobal is a legal move.

Comment: You don't have a `WHERE` condition in your update query, it's going to update ***ALL*** rows. Are you sure you don't mean `INSERT`? Also there's just so much wrong with this code that should have raised a few errors. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` will make sure you actually *see* them.

Comment: @Sammitch I do want it to update them all, there are only 2 rows and will never be more. code has been updated and is not throwing any errors. im really rusty at this, more of my own pet project really. Thanks though

Comment: @PHaeLiX `error_reporting(E_ALL);` sets the error reporting for *subsequent* calls. You should move it to the top of the file so you can see any database call errors. Also look at `mysqli_error()` after `mysqli_query` is called for errors with your SQL syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the complete code. But form fields should be included in `<form>` tags.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Main Title Information</strong></legend>
<div id="prompt">Client Company Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" value="<? echo $companyname; ?>"/></div>
<div id="prompt">Web Tool Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="webtoolname" id="webtoolname" value="<? echo $toolname; ?>"/></div>
<div id="prompt"><input type="submit" id="toolnameupdate" name="toolnameupdate" value="Update Information" /></div><div id="answer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="prompt">&nbsp;</div><div id="answer">&nbsp;</div>
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

also the correct syntax is $_POST['..'], and not with parenthesis.

and also move `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the file, otherwise it won't be too useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, form was there but I deleted it on save. I have also revised the $_POST statements. the form submits now, but the changes are not being added. revised code is below

Comment: thats good to hear. now you need to do some basic database debugging. like checking that your query is successfull when run using the phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST('clientname')` should be `$_POST['clientname']`. And the same with the rest of the posts. Also read Aris's answer about the form tags.

After you revised your code you removed the quotes around the variables, they need to stay.

```
$sql = "UPDATE siteinformation SET clientname = '$companyname1', srcname = '$toolname1'";
```